# Recursive setTimeout() loop not stopped after using clearTimeout()

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, timer

I'm making a simple countdown timer that displays the seconds and setseconds left. When an user clicks a button the countdown should stop and some text should be displayed instead of the timer. Everything works fine on pc but if I use my phone with a worse cpu I sometimes get this unexpected behaviour: when the user clicks the button the text shows for a fraction of a second and then the timer keeps going on. I thought it was caused by the clearTimeout() method being called when the function was running and right before a new timeout would be called but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073548/javascript-deep-thinking-recursive-settimeout-function-with-a-cleartimeout-call) post proved me wrong. Do you have any idea what's causing this behaviour and how should I go about fixing it?

```
const finished = () => { // finished() is also called when user clicks a button
 // show some thext on the screen
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}

const start = document.timeline.currentTime! // Think of it as Date.now(); also returns a ms value; just slightly faster.
const end = start + 30000 // the countodwn takes 30 seconds
let timeout:any;

const frame = () => {
    const elapsed = Math.floor(end - document.timeline.currentTime!)

    if (elapsed <= 0) { 
        finished()
        return
    };

    let secs: number | string = Math.floor(elapsed / 1000)
    let setsecs: number | string = Math.floor((elapsed % 1000) * 0.1)

    secs = secs < 10 ? "0" + secs : secs
    setsecs = setsecs < 10 ? "0" + setsecs : setsecs

    result.innerText = `Time left: ${secs}.${setsecs}`

    timeout = setTimeout(() => requestAnimationFrame(frame), 15 - elapsed % 15) // raf is for optimisation and I'm substracting the timeout by the time that has already passed for drift minimisation
}

frame()
```

EDIT: I managed to recreate the slow behaviour on my phone with promises: [Here's the code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSzAiALApgExgXhgCgEpcA%20GAbxgHor4kUNMiYUYBDAGwhBmE46wwA7hjAwArhHQAnXhwTAA1hHYwARuKhRwAKGq00IITG4BbdDCgYAHrHCWMJ4NPTowemJ%20AC20gCoI5iCa%20FCB6MFQhADcHl7g3AIAdBwgAOb4AAYAYvRoWACEmYQ6AL46OlJQAUEhiMj5mAA0MABMAAydJTqgkLDQvrB4mCDA4uZgUElh5vJg6Elj0i6TNegF%20jB%20qEiKMCBwLLBsKgAibFALYEZE0excPC5Q4tKQqqYqAG6c4uh3AFaSfryNKoKAcACe8BOl2kSR6CVgbmweAG0lgAGoYABmTrtTZWCygcSTECYIRiKBsRToFTYkzoXqYCA6ASwGYRTQALjYYAhsQRfXg0jY5lw7AgELAwAIxBwZHIcV4iJg6A4bAADlIUTAALIXVBJOCpEDSfDImAAWhgIzGEymHLmCyWK2q4QK3U8ngQh3N6q1ggAPHh2sRKEqvXQGowiBGvU8Xu5I6UBZG2QzgBAuTAwOM1DIYAAfExQaRINLi-VWI0ms1qzXa6gwACMeJKafQ-U7Ukz2dzpnzsmL0DLYAreCrhuNIFN%20D9DcEAFIW22YAAqGDtJLNz1ensqVGMlSBlcwAD8MAARO1LzAsfuYNn90qqg-D1AHyfW%20erze7wyPyPR8AOfJVekSBZUgyTI1hgAQ4CgbMABJyH3UokhQ18j1KYoKkjNghDYBBYHmYwAAVpBAUwUHQOcXEST50DlMgqjWSJ8HokAOEYloAFYuhiPCvQ5SJxVY8J2OYeUYBcABHX5oAAQWQUwLgQcBshFcx8DgLSmJaZteOIGgZLYQ5WDgU19g1GYUDU%20xeWwABJAByUwTHENQRzYYAwjHBwLBEzR1ChQlLHCBwLhgVATnuFw2EwKENRORtLNkTAywQmBqJUuywl0codF00VaMIIA)

Comment: Could maybe this thread be a solution to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106189/create-a-simple-10-second-countdown/50846458#50846458

Comment: I copied your code to TypeScript Playground and it works. It might be an issue with your script related to the user button.

Comment: @Edwin it works totally fine on a pc. The issue only occurs on slower cpus. The button script itself is very simple. Basically just a `finished()` callback in the onclick attribute.

Comment: Please have a look on this: [TS Playground](shorturl.at/fqrJ3). I set finish to be fired after 2000 to act like a user event, end after +3000, nextTimeOut after 4000. However, it still works.

Comment: @Edwin Thanks for replying! The code works because the time between the function being called and the timeout being registered is very little on pc. I managed to recreate the behaviour on my slow phone by using a promise that slows down the function. Please take a look: (the link is too long so I'll edit the post and put it there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

### Problem

The time is too short between `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`. A rescheduling is fired behind `clearTimeout`.

### Example

Use a boolean flag to check if that `finished` function had been called.

---

## Solution

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBLAhgJ3gXjgEzCArgWwFMIYA6GASyIBsKJDS9lliYAVKwgQjgHpe4bABZ0A1nDAAzOBXiIocACKIYDCGADuACgCUAbjiJqUMHBYxcyaIbj4FANyO5CBgFa5YCWgHMhMagCecJLyqsikoJCexJhwGEiocADUcADMAAyZfAIwQoRw4LgkYJgaEHAwiKKECqkIhOAQmFDA1ITwlERguDAAXIgQAXrAre3BdBRQeZgAwkZtsRghxoSR0PCSE1OEi3C6cQB8cADe2eMQk9P7k4bGpiDzO3AaeeUehMgFtCCiCohwACMejBIMAzlNNAgwEQKnkAB7wSCw-JQEAsYhguBYzYXbazR6xOIVZDOTFYkBtFAcLo9LSdQjdGA6EZY8lRMBtUjUMDeLQAAwAYltplw+cyAL4jKDtakM2k4y47AA0cAATJl0sy1p5JMhEDCMPIAhAQHsdIcTmSZJItAq8XNqAtzeZLOVGiZOdzeYLhU8Ho6npJuk1SHAABKIez5EGA-IxOB5FikMVW93wQjURAAB2luwAsiohKRJNywMgtPGALRYHAEVjkTi0eiMSwsEiyrjM1kFdmenn8gCimZzO16fJVGezua13Yo0grw9zcAAPBhNSc4Fbu3arl3u6yXVYreLhla2vBpSAoL04BACACPnAAD4IGDIOjeIkF3LF0vlycjrEAgAIwanuWLnvUMCXtet73o+L6wO+ECfhg35FiWYBlloC5Tk8ACkcCgZk5oAFRwOkpDATOrIwUSdHLkR6RwAA-HAABE6Tsck9RXnAN4wVa0rQQ0CjxO0DFMaxHFcTxwl0QJEmiSyrLuhyDBevyspwG0kh9HAAAkxwweKpBGfJoniimVqIBoiCyLehAaHAAAKyDQpMhA4SwHpRuaaBHMJsqMloPkclGKoAKwkfoKlYvSjL0TKnAhfsAWWvuqm9hp-Z8rKnybCwmCiuB+4sAAjs4sAAIIXPgKgUJAAp6kQtotYQpXiiqoHmvwZiININxBp8YBZp0kwNUiAyxAAkgA5PgCC4ACSGICAlAociFQpT0gJBLk0acLCKgJvItwsIgmBBFm8hLsNWDvnptgTPgE2UKCkrALq+peToQA)

```
const start = document.timeline.currentTime! // Think of it as Date.now(); also returns a ms value; just slightly faster.
const end = start + 3000 // the countodwn takes 3 seconds
let timeout:any;

let finishedCalled = false
const finished = () => { // finished() is also called when user clicks a button
 // show some thext on the screen
    finishedCalled  = true
    clearTimeout(timeout)

    console.log(`Finished!`)
}

setTimeout(finished, 2000)

const frame = async () => {
    if(finishedCalled) return console.log(`Finished called found. Have to be end here.`)
    const elapsed = Math.floor(end - document.timeline.currentTime!)
    console.log(`Elapsed:`, elapsed)

    if (elapsed <= 0) { 
        finished()
        return
    };

    let secs: number | string = Math.floor(elapsed / 1000)
    let setsecs: number | string = Math.floor((elapsed % 1000) * 0.1)

    secs = secs < 10 ? "0" + secs : secs
    setsecs = setsecs < 10 ? "0" + setsecs : setsecs

    console.log(`Time left: ${secs}.${setsecs}`)

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Timer fired!`)
        requestAnimationFrame(frame)
    }, 10) // raf is for optimisation and I'm substracting the timeout by the time that has already passed for drift minimisation
}

frame()
```

---

### Dig Deeper

Let's use Node.js as an example and trace down the source.

- [`clearTimeout`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8c4b8b201ada6b76d5306c9c7f352e45087fb4a9/lib/timers.js#L184) called [`unenroll`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8c4b8b201ada6b76d5306c9c7f352e45087fb4a9/lib/timers.js#L78)
- [`unenroll`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8c4b8b201ada6b76d5306c9c7f352e45087fb4a9/lib/timers.js#L78) called [`emitDestroy`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b07894d8dca5d1f3777f257186dec6da835b52ef/lib/internal/async_hooks.js#L524)
- [`emitDestroy` === `emitDestroyScript`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b07894d8dca5d1f3777f257186dec6da835b52ef/lib/internal/async_hooks.js#L611)
- [`emitDestroyScript`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b07894d8dca5d1f3777f257186dec6da835b52ef/lib/internal/async_hooks.js#L524) called [`async_wrap.queueDestroyAsyncId`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/da399a6c8e6ed60313ba0d5dae24d55a1a7c2c37/src/async_wrap.cc#L320)
- [`async_wrap.queueDestroyAsyncId`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/da399a6c8e6ed60313ba0d5dae24d55a1a7c2c37/src/async_wrap.cc#L320) called [`AsyncWrap::EmitDestroy`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/da399a6c8e6ed60313ba0d5dae24d55a1a7c2c37/src/async_wrap.cc#L542)
- [`AsyncWrap::EmitDestroy`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/da399a6c8e6ed60313ba0d5dae24d55a1a7c2c37/src/async_wrap.cc#L542) may or may not execute immediately.

Until this point, we can know it is an async call and may be rescheduled before execute. That's why the `finished` function cannot stop the `timer`.

> Disclaimer: I am not an expert of C++. Please feel free to improve the answer.